# Set Nook Simple Touch back to Stock Reading App

Tags: root-access, reading, aldiko, nook-simple-touch

I've a Nook Simple Touch, rooted, with ReLaunch and Aldiko. I'd like to return to the Stock Reading App (instead of Aldiko).

I can't find the stock reading app. I have 'Open with' available on the context menu but then the stock reading app isn't listed. 'File Associations' will also fail to find the stock app and the intent is being picked up by Aldiko.

How do I get back to opening PDFs and ePUBs in the B&N stock app?

Comment: Have you checked in your app drawer? Also, you could check in *Settings->Apps->Manage Apps*, go to the "All" tab, scroll to Aldiko, and check whether it's set as "default app"; if so, delete the default. Next time, you should be prompted again when opening a book.

Comment: I think @Izzy is right, you have set the default action for opening these file types with Aldiko. You need to go and find the app information for Aldiko and clear the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you install another reading app, then when you open an epub it will offer the choice of reading apps and you can pick the default one "reader". You can then delete the extra reading app.